# Program says that a new directory has been made, but its not visible in destination folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I made a simple c# program that takes a path of a directory, and if that directory doesn't exist, it creates it in the given path, but when I go to the path where it should have been created, no directory is shown.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo DIR = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\A\B");

            try
            {
                if(DIR.Exists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This folder already exists!");
                }
                else
                {
                    DIR.Create();
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder created!");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Folder counldnt be created due to " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem.  This exact code (replacing only "E:\" with "C:\" for my computer) works as expected for me.  When you step through the code in a debugger, what specifically happens?  Is there any exception?  Which statements are executed?  What is the output?  Where are you looking on your computer for the result?  If you execute it again, does the behavior change?  (That is, on the next test, does the code find the folder it just created in the previous test?)

Comment: Looks like it's time for you to do some basic troubleshooting! See what happens if you put `DIR.Delete();`  after you create the directory. Does it throw an exception? If it does that would indicate that `Create()` is both failing and not throwing an exception.

Comment: The program is running perfectly, i am checking the right directory, everything executes flawlessly, but the new directory doesnt appear. If i put the path as @"E:\A\B it prints out "Folder created", and when i run the program a second time with the same path it prints out "This folder already exists", but the directory isnt appearing in that path. I tried adding DIR.Delete() , and it worked as expected, the B directory was "deleted", and when i ran the program again it was again "created" but not appearing.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call that running "flawlessly" if you expected a directory to be created but one wasn't *Not throwing an exception* is not a good bar for "flawless".

Comment: Hello, what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10

Comment: I have tried runnning this code on my laptop and it worked, the directory was created as expected, so that means it has something to do with my computer and hard drive. Do i need to enable specific permissions to be able to write to my hard drive?

Comment: The antivirus was blocking my program from writing to the hard drive, i've turned off my antivirus and it works now :)

Comment: Using [System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory) when the directory already exists won't throw an error, so in many cases there is no need to check if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your program tells you on the second run that the folder already exists I assume you are looking in the wrong place. Do you have multiple computers or is this running in a virtual machine and you are checking on the host? Or is just your explorer not refreshing?

I just added one line `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (DIR.FullName);` to your program that starts the explorer and opens the newly created directory.

If even that will fail you should chkdsk your E: drive, perhaps there is something broken.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      DirectoryInfo DIR = new DirectoryInfo (@"E:\A\B");

      try
      {
        if (DIR.Exists)
        {
          Console.WriteLine ("This folder already exists!");
        }
        else
        {
          DIR.Create ();
          Console.WriteLine ("Folder created!");
          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (DIR.FullName);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine ("Folder counldnt be created due to " + ex);
      }

      Console.ReadKey ();
    }
  }
}
```